# Why is permission denied on this file?

Tags: permissions, docker, php7, bitnami

I am having a strange problem. I am trying to include a file in one of my php files that is in my /assets folder. In the php file I have the line require "/opt/docker-substantiator2/app/application/libraries/koolreport/core/autoload.php";
This line is failing and I am getting the error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Compile Error

Message: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/docker-substantiator2/app/application/libraries/koolreport/core/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php')

Filename: assets/MyReport.php

Line Number: 4
```

I assumed that my phpStorm didn't have the correct permissions to access autoload.php. So then I ran the following from the CLI:

```
richb201@richb201-XPS-13-9370:/opt/docker-substantiator2/app/application/libraries/koolreport/core$ ls -l /opt/docker-substantiator2/app/application/libraries/koolreport/core/autoload.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 richb201 richb201 1803 May 19 04:35 /opt/docker-substantiator2/app/application/libraries/koolreport/core/autoload.php
```

As you can see I (richb201) am the owner and all permissions are available. I have no idea what the include_path comment in the error is about? Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Well, someone asked me why I was checking for autoload.php on the host when I want to know about the autoload.php in the container? So I opened a CLI into the running container with docker exec -it bc0 /bin/bash. Now when I ls-l autoload.php I get: root@bc07d781b0ff:/app/application/libraries/koolreport/core# ls -l autoload.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1001 1001 1803 May 19 08:35 autoload.php
NOTICE: The owner has changed from richb201 (on the host) to 1001 on the container. I can probably chown that file to richb201:richb201, but how can I change it permanently to richb201? I am using docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not include just any file; just like the Linux $PATH variable for executable files, PHP maintains an include path. Only files on this path will be included, and attempts to include a file from outside that path generate an error.

Edit your `php.ini` file and change the `include_path` parameter to what you need, e.g.:

```
include_path = ".:/home/USERNAME/include_directory"
```

Separate paths to directories with the `:` character.